# How to find the coordinate that is closest to the another coordinate? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, coordinates

We have a list of many waypoints containing Latitude and Longitude.

```
0: {order: '1', lat: '59.36517', lng: '24.71795', type: 'waypoint', distance: 8225.839271423867}
1: {order: '2', lat: '59.36683', lng: '24.71798', type: 'waypoint', distance: 8047.60794553467}
2: {order: '3', lat: '59.36955', lng: '24.71765', type: 'waypoint', distance: 7762.290773339123}
3: {order: '4', lat: '59.37130', lng: '24.71726', type: 'waypoint', distance: 7582.402618060507}
4: {order: '5', lat: '59.37235', lng: '24.71759', type: 'waypoint', distance: 7465.330388651929}
5: {order: '6', lat: '59.37258', lng: '24.71761', type: 'waypoint', distance: 7440.570044348184}
6: {order: '7', lat: '59.37350', lng: '24.71812', type: 'waypoint', distance: 7334.306732704424}
7: {order: '8', lat: '59.37383', lng: '24.71796', type: 'waypoint', distance: 7301.993261275825}
8: {order: '9', lat: '59.37521', lng: '24.71792', type: 'waypoint', distance: 7156.449114689986}
```

How can we find the closest waypoint for this point

```
{type:'user_device', lat: '59.37441', lng: '24.71794'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've already found an answer here:
https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/find-record-with-closest-latitude-longitude-from-stringifyed-data-in-localstorage/23845

```
function closestLocation(targetLocation, locationData) {
    function vectorDistance(dx, dy) {
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }

    function locationDistance(location1, location2) {
        var dx = location1.latitude - location2.latitude,
            dy = location1.longitude - location2.longitude;

        return vectorDistance(dx, dy);
    }

    return locationData.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        var prevDistance = locationDistance(targetLocation , prev),
            currDistance = locationDistance(targetLocation , curr);
        return (prevDistance < currDistance) ? prev : curr;
    });
}

var data = [
    {
        "latitude": "57.6494",
        "longitude": "-3.5606"
    },
    {
        "latitude": "57.077",
        "longitude": "-2.836"
    },

],
targetLocation = {latitude: 56, longitude: -5 },

closest = closestLocation(targetLocation, data);
//closest is now the location that is closest to the target location
```